# I'm suppose to write code to check that the user input for the email address contains 1 occurrence of "@" and ".". Plese help me debug

Tags: jupyter-notebook

email = input("Enter your email address: ")

if (email.contain("@") and email.contain(".")):
print( email + " is a VALID email address")
else:
print( email + "is an INVALID email address")

Comment: Clearly this will allow some invalid emails (trivially, it has no length limit), but how do you know it's not sufficient as-is? What should it do that it does not do?

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem easily using regex.

```
import re

EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r"^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$")


email = input("Enter your email address:")

if EMAIL_REGEX.match(email):
    print("It's a valid email!")
else:
    print("It's not a valid email!")
```

**Output :**

```
Enter your email address:dinesh@@gmail.com
It's not a valid email!

Enter your email address:dinesh@gmail..com
It's not a valid email

Enter your email address:dinesh@gmail.c.m
It's not a valid email!

Enter your email address:dinesh@gmail.com
It's a valid email!
```

[image]